# How to pass Dict as the argument to method Julia

Tags: julia

Hello i trying create converter method from Disct to Vector in Julia language.
But i receive error, with i can't understand

```
ERROR: TypeError: Tuple: in parameter, expected Type{T}, got Dict{AbstractString,Int64}
```

My code

```
type Family
    name::UTF8String
    value::Int
end

function convertToVector(a1::Dict{AbstractString, Int64}())
              A::Vector{Node}
          for k in sort(collect(keys(a1)))
              push!(A, Family(a1[k] , k))
              end
          return A
       end
```

Any idea hot to change convertToVector method ?

Comment: maybe just a typo. it should be `a1::Dict{AbstractString, Int64}` not `a1::Dict{AbstractString, Int64}()`

Comment: Yes its, work, but i have another problem A not defined in convertToVector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several typos in the above code, but I think this should work:

```
# No () after the type of a1
# Also, see comment, better to parameterize function, use concrete type for Dict
function convertToVector{T<:AbstractString}(a1::Dict{T, Int64})
    # This is how you create an empty vector to hold Family objects
    A = Vector{Family}()
    for k in sort(collect(keys(a1)))
        # The values passed to the Family constructor were backwards
        push!(A, Family(k, a1[k]))
    end
    A
end
```

Comment: and make `convertToVector{T<:AbstractString}(a1::Dict{T, Int64})` parametric is necessary, i guess.

Comment: That would be much better, I agree (`Dict{AbstractString, Int64}` will work, but it's not efficient).  I was just attempting to fix the bugs in the code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way (probably not very quick):

```
julia> dict = Dict("fred" => 3, "jim" => 4)
Dict{ASCIIString,Int64} with 2 entries:
  "fred" => 3
  "jim"  => 4

julia> Vector{Family}(map(f -> Family(f...), map(x -> collect(x), dict)))
2-element Array{Family,1}:
 Family("fred",3)
 Family("jim",4)
```

Perhaps I've been using too much Lisp recently...